# C++ template function specialization error when specialization is in different header

Tags: c++, function, templates, specialization

In `cnvt.h` header there is:

```
template <typename t_to, typename t_from> std::optional<t_to> cnvt(t_from);
```

And in header `int.h`, we have:

```
#include "cnvt.h" 

template <>
std::optional<uint8_t> cnvt<uint8_t, const char *>(const char *) {
  // actual code replaced for simplicity
  return {};
}
```

As it is, `clang-tidy` reports

> clang reports "int.h:: Included header cvnt.h is not used directly
> (fix available) Included header cvnt.h is not used directly (fix
> available)

And if remove `#include "cnvt.h"`, it reports

> int.h:9:24: No function template matches function template specialization 'cnvt'

I searched StackOverflow, and the posts about function template specialization did not help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This warning comes from clangd rather than clang-tidy. For the code you have written, you do need the `cnvt.h` header included. clangd just doesn't see that you require the primary template from that header for the specialization.

From the [clangd documentation](https://clangd.llvm.org/guides/include-cleaner):

> **I’m using a symbol in a tricky way (e.g. through a template), but the header is marked as unused**
>
> There are some types of uses the analysis cannot find.
>
> Suppress the warning with `// IWYU pragma: keep`

So you should be able to suppress the warning by adding `// IWYU pragma: keep` after the include for `cnvt.h`.

However, if you can I'd recommend side-stepping the problem entirely and using function overloading instead of template specialization:

```
std::optional<uint8_t> cnvt(const char *) {
  // actual code replaced for simplicity
  return {};
}
```

This removes the need for the primary template to be visible in your `int.h` header.

Comment: About the recommandation, `t_to` is not deducible, so usage would be similar to `cnvt<std::uint8_t>(some_text)` incompatible with your version.